# How does the catalan() function works here?

Tags: python, recursion, catalan

I stumbled across this function to calculate the catalan number:

```
def catalan(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        sum = 0
        for i in range (n):
            sum +=(catalan(i))*(catalan(n-1-i))
    return sum
```

My question is how `sum` gets values when for example  `n=2`:

`sum = (catalan(0))*(catalan(2-1-0)) + (catalan(1))*(catalan(2-1-1) + (catalan(2))*(catalan(2-1-2))`

How did `catalan(2-1-0)` or for any other than 0 argument get it's value, if we defined only value for `n=1`?

Comment: _[Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) proves that we can climb as high as we like on a ladder, by proving that we can climb onto the bottom rung (the basis) and that from each rung we can climb up to the next one (the step)._ – [_Concrete Mathematics_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pen and paper evaluation**

catalan (0)

```
# 1
```

catalan (1)

```
#  = 0 + catalan (0) * catalan (1-1-0)
#  = 0 + 1 * catalan (0)
#  = 0 + 1 * 1
#  = 0 + 1
```

catalan (2)

```
#  = 0
#  + catalan (0) * catalan (2-1-0)
#  + catalan (1) * catalan (2-1-1)

#  = 0 
#  + 1 * catalan (1) 
#  + 1 * catalan (0)

#  = 0
#  + 1 * 1
#  + 1 * 1

#  = 1
#  + 1

#  = 2
```

catalan (3)

```
#  = 0
#  + catalan (0) * catalan (3-1-0)
#  + catalan (1) * catalan (3-1-1)
#  + catalan (2) * catalan (3-1-2)

#  = 0
#  + 1 * catalan (2) 
#  + 1 * catalan (1)
#  + 2 * catalan (0)

#  = 0
#  + 1 * 2
#  + 1 * 1
#  + 2 * 1

#  = 0
#  + 2
#  + 1
#  + 2

#  = 5
```

---

**Wasted cycles**

Let's look at a naive fibonacci process –

```
def fib (n):
  if n < 2:
    return n
  else:
    return fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

This procedure is instructive as a prototypical tree recursion, but it is a terrible way to compute Fibonacci numbers because it does so much redundant computation. Notice below that the entire computation of `fib(3)`, almost half the work, is duplicated. In fact, it is not hard to show that the number of times the procedure will compute `fib(1)` or `fib(0)` (the number of leaves in the above tree, in general) is precisely `fib(n + 1)`. To get an idea of how bad this is, one can show that the value of `fib(n)` grows exponentially with `n` — [*SICP - Tree Recursion*](http://www.sicpdistilled.com/section/1.2.2/)

[image: wasteful fibonacci]

A similar problem is happening with you `catalan` program, but to an even worse degree. Calling `catalan(3)` will yield *six* (6) additional `catalan` calls

```
# catalan (3)
#  = 0
#  + catalan (0) * catalan (3-1-0)
#  + catalan (1) * catalan (3-1-1)
#  + catalan (2) * catalan (3-1-2)
#  ...
#  = 5
```

There are multiple techniques available to avoid this problem. Follow the citation above for more help on the topic.