# How to do recursion by hand?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am having a brain lapse in recursion and trying to get the math right. The function gives me what I want but my brain does not.

```js
let recurseSum = (x, n) => {
    if(n === 1){ return x}

    return x + recurseSum(x, n-1)
}

log = console.log
log(recurseSum(3, 2))
```

How is this broken down again, the answer and what I write is not right.

```
3 + recurse(3, (2-1) = 3 + 1 = 4
3 + resurse(3, (1-1) = 3....ggrrrrrrr
```

How do I write this out properly.

Comment: Have you considered adding `console.log` into the function to help you understand the process? E.g. a `console.log(x); console.log(n)` before the return would help you see what is being summed

Comment: `if(n === 1){ return x}` - so on the 2nd iteration, you return 3, not 1, so your first written down line would be `3 + recurse(3, (2-1)) = 3 + 3 = 6`

Comment: With no assumptions, this is what I got when I "wrote down" the recursion:  https://jsfiddle.net/9agpfyLx/

Comment: I get it now and thanks for the comments

Comment: `const recurseSum = (x, n) => n<2 ? x : x + recurseSum(x,--n);`

Comment: I'd change the base case to `if (n < 1) { return 0 }`. This gives more sensible results when called with `n < 1` and requires less mental effort to understand, at the cost of one extra stack frame per call. This is a pretty contrived use of recursion, in any case. `x * n` is the way to go. It's OK to use recursion for pedagogical purposes, but there are better examples of it that will also make more sense on every level, and be useful to know.

Comment: I think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010967/633183) helpful.

Comment: Thanks, for the link. and also I am curious what is the best way to learn recursion better? 

I have noticed it is better to set the base case to 1. 0 causes issues a lot of the time, i dont get why yet

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments I have answered my own question

```
3 + recurseSum(3, 2)
3 + recurseSum(3, 1) returned

Bubbles back up 3 + 3 = 6

For some reason i was .... I needed to ask
3 + 3, (3-1) = 6 counter = 2
6 + 3, (2-1) = 9 counter = 1 return
x = 0; for a new person recursion is tough.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some logging to see how it actually behaves, no need to type this stuff out manually

```js
let recurseSum = (x, n) => {
  let val;
  if(n === 1){
    val = x;
  } else {
    val = x + recurseSum(x, n-1);
  }
  console.log(`recurseSum(${x}, ${n}) = ${val}`)
  return val
}

console.log('Final Value: ', recurseSum(3, 2))
```

Comment: In some cases, "old school" manual walk-through an help identify where an assumption vs actual don't concur - *paired* with additional console.logs does make this easier, but being able to manually walk-through code correctly should be a skill all developers have, regardless of the "need" in any specific circumstance.

Comment: True good point, and I suppose different developers work in different ways. For me, I would want to first see what my code actually does and then compare that to what I assume in my head. After wards, if they are different, I can then walk though how it should work to see what needs to change. To each his own though. My "answer" here is just a suggestion or an option available.