# Recursion in Depth

Tags: javascript, recursion

From the code below, I was trying to understand about recursion

```js
function eleven(number) {
  if (number === 1) {
    return number;
    else {
      return number * eleven(number - 1);
    }
  }

  console.log(eleven(5));
```

I can't understand how the last return statement works because its calls itself.

after if condition happens true it should return and stop the code.

but after that else statement returns 120 at last

I need to understand how does the pattern works underneath into the answer 120

is there any resources to get to know more about recursion pattern at core !!

As a beginner How do i master it..

Comment: *"it should return and stop the code."*: That would be strange. There are 5 earlier calls that were made, and which didn't return yet, so the execution cannot just "stop".

Comment: How do you make 10 pizzas? You make 1 pizza, and then you make 9 pizzas. How do you make 9 pizzas? You make 1 pizza, and then you make 8 pizzas. ...

Comment: Why is this called "eleven"? It's clearly calculating factorial.

Comment: `it should return and stop the code.` <-- I think this is the bit that's confusing you; each function call returns its value *to whatever called it in the first place*; just because it's a return doesn't mean the code stops running.   The first call to the function gets returned to you; the second one where it calls itself gets returned to the first call, the third call gets returned to the second call, etc.

Comment: Also it's good to not "overthink" the issue. However adding `console.log()` calls to your function might help you see what's going on.

Comment: Giving the function a good name is a good starting point. If the name is meaningless, or misleading, it's that much harder to understand what it's supposed to do and how it goes about doing that. Start with the function contract (name, inputs and outputs). Interestingly, [similar code was posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77517670/how-to-do-recursion-by-hand). Not sure why schools are pushing these rather questionable examples of recursion. I suggest a better base case in that thread--this will crash if called with 0 or less. The code here has a syntax error also.